# Data by multiple conditions from checkpoints columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I had a problem with the speed of processing my data. There is a dataframe of three blocks: name, signs, control points. And to put it simply, I need to collect names with features in one table for all control points line by line. Breakpoint values indicate which features to choose for each item!

I used concatenation with a loop. And it turned out to be too slow for me. About 20-30 seconds. And I feel that it can be accelerated, but I don't know how. I need it to take 2-3 seconds. Tell me, please, did I choose the method of indexing the feature search by the values of all control points incorrectly? How can I improve or fundamentally change the code?

Here is the description of the dataframe:

- item ('index', 'name', 'country')
- Various signs by groups 'c', 'd' ('a1_b1_c_foo', 'a1_b1_c_foo_bar', ..., 'a1_b1_d_foo_bar_baz', ...)
- Several checkpoints for each item ('point_1' 'point_1_description', ..., 'point_2', ...). Each checkpoint contains refinement values for extracting specific feature columns ('point_1_a', point_1_b', ....)

I have shown a simplified dataframe in the example. To understand the approximate amount of data, I will write how much data a real dataframe will contain:

- Tens of thousands of lines (items)
- Fifteen signs of group 'c', ten signs of group 'd'
- 'a1_ ...' 'a2_ ...'    planned from 1 to 15
- '*b1* ...' '*b2* ...'    planned from 1 to 3
- 40 checkpoints

| index | name | country | a1_b1_c_foo | a1_b1_c_foo_bar | a1_b1_d_foo_bar_baz | a2_b1_c_foo | a2_b1_c_foo_bar | a2_b1_d_foo_bar_baz | a1_b2_c_foo | a1_b2_c_foo_bar | a1_b2_d_foo_bar_baz | a2_b2_c_foo | a2_b2_c_foo_bar | a2_b2_d_foo_bar_baz | a1_b3_c_foo | a1_b3_c_foo_bar | a1_b3_d_foo_bar_baz | a2_b3_c_foo | a2_b3_c_foo_bar | a2_b3_d_foo_bar_baz | point_1 | point_1_description | point_1_a | point_1_b | point_2 | point_2_description | point_2_a | point_2_b | point_3 | point_3_description | point_3_a | point_3_b | point_4 | point_4_description | point_4_a | point_4_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bernard | France | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 | value8 | value9 | value10 | value11 | value12 | value13 | value14 | value15 | value16 | value17 | value18 | name1 | description1 | 1 | 1 | name2 | description2 | 2 | 1 | name3 | description3 | 1 | 2 | name4 | description4 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | Elon | USA | value19 | value20 | value21 | value22 | value23 | value24 | value25 | value26 | value27 | value28 | value29 | value30 | value31 | value32 | value33 | value34 | value35 | value36 | name5 | description5 | 1 | 2 | name6 | description6 | 1 | 2 |  |  |  |  | name8 | description8 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Jeff | USA | value37 | value38 | value39 | value40 | value41 | value42 | value43 | value44 | value45 | value46 | value47 | value48 | value49 | value50 | value51 | value52 | value53 | value54 | name9 | description9 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |  | name11 | description11 | 2 | 2 | name12 | description12 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | Lawrence | USA | value55 | value56 | value57 | value58 | value59 | value60 | value61 | value62 | value63 | value64 | value65 | value66 | value67 | value68 | value69 | value70 | value71 | value72 | name13 | description13 | 1 | 2 | name14 | description14 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  | name16 | description16 | 1 | 2 |

In the final table, what I want to get: all control points are collected with the corresponding characteristics, which are determined depending on the value of the columns 'point_...*a', 'point*...b'.

An example of a summary table:

|  | name | country | c_foo | c_foo_bar | d_foo_bar_baz | point | point_description | point_a | point_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Bernard | France | value1 | value2 | value9 | name1 | description1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Elon | USA | value25 | value26 | value33 | name5 | description5 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Jeff | USA | value40 | value41 | value48 | name9 | description9 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Lawrence | USA | value61 | value62 | value69 | name13 | description13 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | Bernard | France | value4 | value5 | value12 | name2 | description2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | Elon | USA | value25 | value26 | value33 | name6 | description6 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Lawrence | USA | value55 | value56 | value63 | name14 | description14 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | Bernard | France | value7 | value8 | value15 | name3 | description3 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | Bernard | France | value7 | value8 | value15 | name4 | description4 | 1 | 2 |

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('test_r.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='   ', low_memory=False)





collist_tmp = [
    "a1_b1_c_foo",
    "a1_b1_c_foo_bar",
    "a1_b1_d_foo_bar_baz",
    "a2_b1_c_foo",
    "a2_b1_c_foo_bar",
    "a2_b1_d_foo_bar_baz",
    "a1_b2_c_foo",
    "a1_b2_c_foo_bar",
    "a1_b2_d_foo_bar_baz",
    "a2_b2_c_foo",
    "a2_b2_c_foo_bar",
    "a2_b2_d_foo_bar_baz",
    "a1_b3_c_foo",
    "a1_b3_c_foo_bar",
    "a1_b3_d_foo_bar_baz",
    "a2_b3_c_foo",
    "a2_b3_c_foo_bar",
    "a2_b3_d_foo_bar_baz",
    ]

collist_d = [
    "d_foo_bar_baz",
    ]

collist_final_df = [
    "name",
    "country",
    "c_foo",
    "c_foo_bar",
    "d_foo_bar_baz",
    'point',
    'point_description',
    'point_a',
    'point_b',
    ]





# assembly checkpoints "point"
list_dfs = []





# loop
for i in range(1,5):

    collist_c = [
        "name",
        "country",
        "c_foo",
        "c_foo_bar",
        'point_' + str(i),
        'point_' + str(i) + '_description',
        'point_' + str(i) + '_a',
        'point_' + str(i) + '_b',
        ]
    
    collist_df_all = [
        "name",
        "country",
        "c_foo",
        "c_foo_bar",
        "d_foo_bar_baz",
        'point_' + str(i),
        'point_' + str(i) + '_description',
        'point_' + str(i) + '_a',
        'point_' + str(i) + '_b',
        ]


    df = df.loc[~df[f'point_{i}'].isnull()]

    # tmp
    tmp = df.reindex(columns=collist_tmp)
    tmp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tmp.columns.str.extract('(a[^_]+_b[^_]+)_(.*)'))

    # group c
    target_c = 'a'+ (pd.Series(df[f'point_{i}_a'].astype('Int16') + 0, dtype='string')) + '_b'+ (df[f'point_{i}_b'].astype('Int16').astype(str)) 
    df_c = (df
    .reset_index()
    .merge(tmp.stack(level=0, dropna=False), left_on=['index', target_c], right_index=True)
    .set_index('index')[collist_c]
    .reset_index()
    )

    # group d
    target_d = 'a'+ (df[f'point_{i}_a'].astype('Int16').astype(str)) + '_b'+ (pd.Series(df[f'point_{i}_b'].astype('Int16') + 1, dtype='string'))
    df_d = (df
    .reset_index()
    .merge(tmp.stack(level=0, dropna=False), left_on=['index', target_d], right_index=True)
    .set_index('index')[collist_d]
    .reset_index()
    )

    # assembly df with group c and group d
    df_all = pd.concat(
        objs=(iDF.set_index('index') for iDF in (df_c, df_d)),
        axis=1, 
        join='inner'
    ).reset_index().drop(columns=['index']).reindex(columns=collist_df_all)





    df_all.columns = collist_final_df

    # assembly checkpoints "point"
    list_dfs.append(df_all)






# assembly checkpoints "point"
df_final = pd.concat(list_dfs)

print(df_final)
```

Comment: kindly align your output dataframe to match the sample input dataframe you shared

Comment: @sammywemmy Corrected dataframes

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: Corrected the description of my problem. There is a dataframe of three blocks: name, signs, control points. And to put it simply, I need to collect names with features in one table for all control points line by line. Breakpoint values indicate which features to choose for each item!